# SqlAlchemy & pyMysql connection pooling on a lambda with multiple DB connections

Tags: python, database, lambda, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

So the issue is I have multiple databases that I want to use the same Database Pool in SqlAlchemy. This resides on a Lambda and the pool is created upon initiation of the Lambda. I want the subsequent DB connections to use the existing pool.

What works just fine is the initial pool connection `bpConnect` and any subsequent queries to that connection.

What **DOESN'T** work is the `companyConnect` connection. I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.AttributeError) 'XRaySession' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

I have these for my connections:

```
# Pooling
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool

#################### Engines ###################################################
def bpGetConnection():
    engine_endpoint = f"mysql+pymysql://{os.environ['DB_USERNAME']}:{os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']}@{os.environ['DB_HOST']}:{str(os.environ['DB_PORT'])}/{os.environ['database']}"
    engine = create_engine(engine_endpoint, echo_pool=True)
    session = XRaySessionMaker(bind=engine, autoflush=True, autocommit=False)
    db = session()
    return db

bpPool = pool.StaticPool(bpGetConnection)

def companyGetConnection(database):
    engine_endpoint = f"mysql+pymysql://{os.environ['DB_USERNAME']}:{os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']}@{os.environ['DB_HOST']}:{str(os.environ['DB_PORT'])}/{database}"
    compEngine = create_engine(engine_endpoint, pool=bpPool)
    session = XRaySessionMaker(bind=compEngine, autoflush=True, autocommit=False)
    db = Session()
    return db

#################### POOLING #############################################

def bpConnect():
    conn = bpPool.connect()
    return conn

def companyConnect(database):
    conn = companyGetConnection(database)
    return conn

#################################################################
```

They are called in this example:

```
from connections import companyConnect, bpConnect
from models import Company, Customers

def getCustomers(companyID):
    db = bpConnect()
    myQuery = db.query(Company).filter(Company.id == companyID).one()

    compDB = companyConnect(myQuery.database)
    customers = compDB.query(Customers).all()
    return customers
```

Comment: Also to be noted that `sessionmaker()` AND `XRaySessionMaker()` both result in the same error and it isn't the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it with dynamic pools on a lambda:

```
class DBRegistry(object):
    _db = {}

    def get(self, url, **kwargs):
        if url not in self._db:
            engine = create_engine(url, **kwargs)
            Session = XRaySessionMaker(bind=engine, autoflush=True, autocommit=False)
            session = scoped_session(Session)
            self._db[url] = session
        return self._db[url]

compDB = DBRegistry()

def bpGetConnection():
    engine_endpoint = f"mysql+pymysql://{os.environ['DB_USERNAME']}:{os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']}@{os.environ['DB_HOST']}:{str(os.environ['DB_PORT'])}/{os.environ['database']}?charset=utf8"
    engine = create_engine(engine_endpoint)
    session = XRaySessionMaker(bind=engine, autoflush=True, autocommit=False)
    db = session()
    return db

bpPool = pool.QueuePool(bpGetConnection, pool_size=500, timeout=11)

def bpConnect():
    conn = bpPool.connect()
    return conn

def companyConnect(database):
    engine_endpoint = f"mysql+pymysql://{os.environ['DB_USERNAME']}:{os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']}@{os.environ['DB_HOST']}:{str(os.environ['DB_PORT'])}/{database}?charset=utf8"
    conn = compDB.get(engine_endpoint, poolclass=QueuePool)
    return conn
```

So basically it will use one pool for the constant connection needed on the main database and another pool which it will dynamically change the database it needs. When a connection to one of those company databases is needed, it will check if that pool already exists in the registry of pools. If the pool does not exist it will create one and register it.